# RaptorQ FEC Implementation Obstacle

Tags: linear-algebra, codec, forwarderrorcorrection

I am trying to implement the RaptorQ Forward Error Correction Scheme in java as specified here:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rmt-bb-fec-raptorq-04#section-5.3.3

The core of the problem is actually to execute gaussian elimination on a matrix A in a smart way to be fast.

The matrix A is composed of submatrices, among others these are G_LDPC,1 and G_LDPC,2.
(Generator matrices for Low Density Parity Checks)

On page 22 in section "5.3.3.3. Pre-coding relationships" it is stated that this matrices can be decuced from the code snippet on the same page.

My Problem: I am not able to derive the structure of these two submatrices from the code snipped.

Does someone see how to do that, or how the structure looks like?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Max

Comment: I believe you are not be able to implement it from IETF and specially with Java. Usually people think that these codes can be easily implemented by IETF, but I assure you there is not such things. I believe you have to use Matlab to get over the problem, but before that you need to start to learn many kind of codes for few months until you can have proper idea of Raptor codes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also trying to implement RaptorQ, and ran into this exactly same problem. My suggestion is this book:

Raptor Codes (Foundations and Trends(R) in Communications and Information Theory) [Paperback]
Amin Shokrollahi (Author), Michael Luby (Author)

It has a better explanation on constructing the constraint matrix in section 3.3.3 (I'd quote it, but I don't have it digital).

@Max anyway we can chat or you can share your RFC5053 implementation? I really could use someone familiar with these difficulties to talk to and share some doubts/ideas.

Comment: Implementation of RaptorQ (RFC6330) in Java done. It seems to be possible, but really had to bang my head against the wall sometimes.

Comment: is it open source?
many people including me will be very interested in it.
since you have implemented it in Java, it can be easily ported to Android.

Comment: @tcboy88 yes, it will be open source and public domain in the next few months. by the way, do you know of any other public domain implementation out there?

Comment: sazr, have you posted anywhere? I'm very interested in such open source projects.

Comment: @tcboy88, you can find the project's webpage [here](https://zemasa.github.io/OpenRQ/). We have a well-documented API imho, but we're still working on getting a wiki out (with some code snippets). In regards to the API you can use simple byte array methods, for a quick and dirty integration; or you can use our NIO methods which will offer you the best performance.

Comment: the answer is also for you @Mtr

Comment: @sazr Has the link to the project's homepage changed to this? https://github.com/openrq-team/OpenRQ

Answer (score 1):

After being stuck with the problem, I decided to implement the Raptor codec according to RFC 5053 as described here:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5053

This is actually the predecessor version of RaptorQ.
The general working principle seems to be the same, but it is less optimized and therefore has worse properties, especially in sense of reception efficiency.
But on the other hand it was less complex and more intuitive to me, and therefore I was able to code a working implementation in Java.
And after all, I have to admit that I'm very astonished by the capabilities of the created codec!

With the deeper understanding gained during coding the RFC 5053 implementation I was probably also able to realize the RaptorQ codec now.

Comment: Do you try to implement raptorQ in matlab? Could you share it?